# i want to compare a value that is encrypted in mariaDB with the value tha a user has set in the login

Tags: php, encryption, mariadb

I have a column `passwd` that I have encrypted with the algorithm `PASSWORD()`. I want to compare the password that a user has put in with
the variable that is stored in the database. I want to encrypt the value first in another variable and the compare them.

I change the column like this:

```
UPDATE customer SET passwd_enc=PASSWORD(passwd);
```

I do the login like this:

```
<?php
$u = $_REQUEST['username'];
$p = $_REQUEST['pass'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE uname=? AND  passwd_enc=?";
if(! $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}else( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $u,$p);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if($row['uname']==$u && $row['passwd_enc']==$p) {
        print "Welcome $u";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $u;

    } else {
        print "Unknown user";
        $_SESSION['username'] = '?';
    }

    if($row['is_admin']==1){
        $_SESSION['is_admin']='admin';
    }else{
        $_SESSION['is_admin']='user';
    }
}
?>
```

Something like this:

```
$p=$_REQUEST['pass'];
$p_enc=encrypt($p);
if($p==(encrypted variable in db))
```

NOTE: I want the encyption to be done like the `PASSWORD()` function.

Comment: why would you want to use this and not `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`?

Comment: Please in future pay more attention to your grammar, spelling and formatting. You do not need to use the ` symbol if you have already used four spaces.

Comment: @Tiskolin Seems a bit harsh, it's the OPs first question...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you can use `password_hash()` and `pasword_verify()`.
Store the result of `password_hash($plainTextPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` in your database. Then check instead of checking it like

```
$p=$_REQUEST['pass'];
$p_enc=encrypt($p);
if($p==(encrypted variable in db))
```

Check it like this:

```
if (password_verify($_REQUEST['pass'], $encryptedVariableFromDB)){
  // Do stuff.
}
```

Note that:

1. You don't have to use `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`, I added it to show that that parameter is available. To quote the manual: "*Note that this constant* [i.e. PASSWORD_DEFAULT] *is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP.*"
2. You talk about encryption in your answer. You actually want to [hash the password instead of encrypting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms).